# VBA Sort columns by one column in different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have an excel file with 9 Worksheets, each worksheet has A **different amount of columns and A dynamic amount of rows**.

When I activate A worksheet I refer to it with A variable called "WS" as Worksheet type.

The one thing all worksheets has in common is A column with the header "Brand" which is always column "B".

Column "B" always has data in it but other columns have full and empty cells in them.

At the moment what my code does is adding new products at the first empty row of the worksheet I chose.

I want to add A sort to it, so after every time I add A product to one of the worksheets it will then sort the full table ascending in that worksheet by the "Brand" column (column "B"), I need that the full row will be sorted according to the data in column "B".

For example:

1. I have A worksheet named "Storage".
2. I added A new item - the item has 8 columns of data in the next order:

   Barcode, Brand, Model, Lighting, Type, Size, Speed, Price
3. Now I want to sort it ascending by the name of the brand in column "B".
4. After the sort, considering that the data was entered to row 50 and the last row that has the same brand name is row 25, then I need all the data from row 50 to be inserted in row 26.

How do I do that?

I hope that what I explained is easy to understand and that someone would be able to help me.

Comment: when you sort the data after adding new row. The new row will automatically get sorted, you just need to add a sort method to column B like this (Columns("A:H").Sort key1:=Range("B2"), order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes)

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked perfect. is there a way to do it as a function with dynamic columns as well in case i want to add more columns in the future?

Comment: Functions can't perform operations, they can only return values. You need a( Sub Procedure )for this task.